# AJAX - PHP save data repeated

Tags: php, ajax

I've a form with data repeated:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="myForm">
  <?php foreach ($array as $value) { ?>
    <input type="text" name="myInput[]" id="myInput" value="<?php $value->data1 ?>"/>
    <textarea name="myTextArea[]" id="myTextArea"><?php $value->data2 ?></textarea>
  <?php } ?>
<a href="#" id="submit">save</a>
</form>
```

I try to save values with ajax with this script:

```
 jQuery(function(){
  jQuery("#submit").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = {
        'myInput'     : jQuery('input[name=myInput]').val(),
        'myTextArea'  : jQuery("textarea#myTextArea").val()
    };
    jQuery.ajax({
        url     : 'someUrl', 
        type    : 'POST', 
        data    : formData,
        dataType: 'json', 
        encode  : true,
        success: function(response){
             if (response.success==true) {

             }
             else {

             }
        }
    });
});
});
```

When data is not repeated (no array values) i've no problem, but in this case something goes wrong. Anyone could help me?

Comment: try serializing a form using jQuery and see if that works.

Comment: @Dharmavir how can I manage serialized data?

Comment: You've got the answer.! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, use

```
data: $(this).serialize()
```

in your jQuery submit function. Leave the square brackets in the input names intact. In your PHP, you will be able to access your data like this:

```
$myInputs = $_POST['myInput'];
$myTextAreas = $_POST['myTextArea'];
```

Both variables will be arrays of values retrieved from the form. More info on PHP arrays is available [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

EDIT: If you need the value of $myInputs as a string separated by commas (e.g., "value1, value2, value3..." instead of array with "value1" etc.), you could do the following right after:

```
$myInputs = implode(', ', $myInputs); // this will convert the array to a string
```

Comment: hi Sergey, thanks for answer.
I leave brackets in input name but post data seems incorrect: myInput[]: value1, myTextArea[]: valueA, myInput[]: value2, myTextArea[]: valueB. I expect something like: myInput[value1, value2], myTextArea[valueA, ValueB]. What do you think about that?

Comment: It won't work like this. And not knowing what exactly you're after, it's hard to make suggestions. I've modified my answer above slightly, perhaps it will help.

Comment: I try to print data in php file and my post data is correct. Thank you man!

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery code :

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery("#submit").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $("#myForm").serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url     : 'someUrl', 
        type    : 'POST', 
        data    : formData,
        dataType: 'json', 
        encode  : true,
        success: function(response){
             if (response.success==true) {

             }
             else {

             }
        }
    });
});
});
```

Please refer this answer to add multiple textbox values in database : [Adding multiple textbox entry to a mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875899/adding-multiple-textbox-entry-to-a-mysql-database)

Comment: I did it. But i don't know how use data in php file. Ajax post values like: myInput=something&myTextArea=otherthing&myInput=somethingelse&myTextArea=otherthingelse.... I don't know how discriminate values